featch webrtc fails with src/third_party/test_fonts error
I tried to fetch Windows WebRTC using the command:
fetch --nohooks webrtcrtc
as I have done many times before.
The fetch worked fine until the last steps. At the end, it gave me an error about src/third_party/test_fonts.
Do you have any ideas on how to overcome this issue? I need to automate the build, so unfortunately, one-time manual solutions are not an option.
====== Error Details
Syncing projects: 100% (49/49) src/third_party/test_fonts/test_fonts:f26f29c9d3bfae588207bbc9762de8d142e58935c62a86f673
src/buildtools/win-format:49458d4c1e884a38308f8dc6a2c7eb55fc478755 (ERROR)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F://google//depot_tools//metrics.py", line 290, in print_notice_and_exit
yield
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient.py", line 4612, in /<module/>
sys.exit(main(sys.argv/[1:/]))
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient.py", line 4598, in main
return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
File "F://google//depot_tools//subcommand.py", line 254, in execute
return command(parser, args/[1:/])
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient.py", line 3951, in CMDsync
ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient.py", line 2434, in RunOnDeps
work_queue.flush(revision_overrides,
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient_utils.py", line 1026, in flush
reraise(e/[0/], e/[1/], e/[2/])
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient_utils.py", line 53, in reraise
raise value
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient_utils.py", line 1105, in run
self.item.run(/*self.args, /*/*self.kwargs)
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient.py", line 2717, in run
self.DownloadGoogleStorage()
File "F://google//depot_tools//gclient.py", line 2822, in DownloadGoogleStorage
raise Exception(f'{code}: {err}')
Exception: 1: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F://google//depot_tools//gsutil.py", line 318, in /<module/>
sys.exit(main())
File "F://google//depot_tools//gsutil.py", line 314, in main
return run_gsutil(args.target, args.args, clean=args.clean)
File "F://google//depot_tools//gsutil.py", line 222, in run_gsutil
gsutil_bin = ensure_gsutil(VERSION, target, clean)
File "F://google//depot_tools//gsutil.py", line 114, in ensure_gsutil
with zipfile.ZipFile(target_zip_filename, 'r') as target_zip:
File "C://Users//asus//AppData//Local.vpython-root//store//cpython+71j6rfmckko9jbfin82n7ep9to//contents//bin//Lib//zipfile.py", line 1304, in __init__
self./_RealGetContents()
File "C://Users//asus//AppData//Local.vpython-root//store//cpython+71j6rfmckko9jbfin82n7ep9to//contents//bin//Lib//zipfile.py", line 1371, in /_RealGetContents
raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

i search online,but have no idea.what shoule I do?
